# Master Page for Windows Phone 8.1 development

Tags: windows-phone, master-pages, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any method to create the Master Page for the Windows Phone 8.1 Development? I can't find any article about the master page for the wp8.1, is it not possible to make it or what? Since I'm lazy to make so many page with same layout in the Windows Phone 8.1 design, so I'm thinking of making the master page of it to make all the layout similar. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks and appreciate for the one who helped me out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you'll be able to create a base page if you've used the MVVM model. There are many ways to get the `ViewModel` where you want it to be, that is in the View's `DataContext`. Though you could do it purely in XAML, Microsoft suggests to set the `DataContext` like:

```
DataContext = App.MainViewModel;
```

For more you could refer these:

[WP8 how to create base-page & use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398590/)

[XAML Databinding singleton-like MVVM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397824/)

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, your link would help me a lot. :)